# physical address & logical address

Tags: memory, memory-address

I'd like to ask why we have to get an physical address not directly (if it would be placed in Logical Address) but first obtain segment and this physical address from such segment (in Linear Address Space). Why not directly from Logical? Is it impossible that Dir|Table|Offset addresses would be placed just in Logical Address Far Pointer?
[image]

Comment: I hope [Mel Gorman's book](http://kernel.org/doc/gorman/) is useful to you.

Comment: is this just first impression or really there is a lot of additional information and what I need is some more simple doc? I am afraid it will be difficult to find there what is really of matter here

Comment: The thing is, the Intel memory management isn't really _simple_ -- there is the segments and then there is the paging, and to my knowledge, only [one operating system uses the segments as Intel designed](http://www.aesec.com/) -- but I could be misunderstanding the `get_fs()` and related macros in the Linux kernel sources...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between physical/logical/virtual memory address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851225/difference-between-physical-logical-virtual-memory-address)